# Why can't I use: "await .getAttribute()" in Protractor, even though it returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, protractor, angular-e2e

I am trying to change my Protractor tests to use async/await instead of the selenium control flow, but it won't let me use await for the .getAttribute() function. All i get is this error Message: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function". But shouldn't .getAttribute() be async since it returns a promise?

Here is one of many examples where i get this error:

```
this.navBarcreator = async () => {        
    var mapArray = {}

    await element.all(by.tagName('mat-list-item')).each((elem) => {
        var tmp = await elem.getAttribute('aria-describedby')
        if (tmp != null) {
            ...
        }
    })
```

Comment: Add an async into your `each` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(elem) => {
    var tmp = await elem.getAttribute('aria-describedby')
    if (tmp != null) {
        ...
    }
```

That function is not `async`, and it has to be `async` for `await` to work. Make your callback async and it should work.

```
async (elem) => { //... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we break down your function :

```
// We have this first part which is async/await
this.navBarcreator = async () => {        
    // ...
});
```

---

```
// Then we have this part, where we are calling a function
// using each, and this function is not async/await
// but you are trying to use the keyword await in it
var mapArray = {}

await element.all(by.tagName('mat-list-item')).each((elem) => {
   // ... await ...
});
```

---

A correct syntax would be

```
await element.all(by.tagName('mat-list-item')).each(async (elem) => {
   // ... await ...
});
```

---

But I don't know if the use of an async function is appropriate with `.each`.

Myself, I like to map and return promises that I resolve using a `Promise.all`, like :

```
async function treatElement(x) {
   // ... await ...
}

await Promise.all(myArr.map(x => treatElement(x)));
```